# How to achieve "3 color" shading?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I'm trying to render 3D text model.

I want it to be only 3 main colors for the shadows (of course you need gradients for round surfaces).

I want it to look like this:[image]

I made the gradient shadow under the "P" with Photoshop. Is there a way to achieve this kind of shading with only blender so that I don't have to edit the rendered image afterwards?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you want flat colors for the rendered surfaces instead of gradients?

Comment: Yeah I basically want to have flat colors, but still want to have somekind of realistic shading, as in my example. I don't want the shadows so be all over the place and I dont want to have gradients everywhere, just where it's necessary (at round surfaces, like unter the "P")